# Disable Camel ActiveMQ Consumer Connection logs

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using Spring `DSL` to consume messages.
Everything works fine. The issue is every `5` seconds it checks for connection and logs message:

```
"Successfully connected to ssl://hostname:port"
```

How to disable the connection log?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use, and what component is that consumer? And what logging level is that log shown at?

Comment: I am using the ActiveMQComponent (5.11.0.redhat) and the camel version is 2.18.1.redhat-000015. As per activeMQ log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=WARN didn't worked. I need to set logging.level.org.apache.activemq=WARN to skip the FailoverTransport  log.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the ***logging.level.org.apache.activemq=WARN***

2) If you are using failover set ***warnAfterReconnectAttempts=0***